# Loading matrix in from csv file - golang

Tags: arrays, csv, matrix, go

I'm writing a program that performs math on matrixes. I want to load them in from a csv file and have the following code:

```
    file, err := os.Open("matrix1.csv")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer file.Close()
lines, _ := csv.NewReader(file).ReadAll()
for i, line := range lines {
    for j, val := range line {
        valInt, err := strconv.Atoi(val)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        matrix1[i][j] = valInt
    }
}
```

However the strconv code is throwing an error:

```
strconv.ParseInt: parsing "": invalid syntax
```

It appears that everything else in the code is correct, does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this error?

EDIT: I'm now trying to work on outputting my result to a new csv file.

I have the following code:

```
    file2, err := os.Create("result.csv")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer file1.Close()

writer := csv.NewWriter(file2)
for line2 := range blank {
    writer.Write(line2)
}

}
```

}

This gives the following error:

```
 cannot use line2 (type int) as type []string in argument to writer.Write
```

Updated with the suggestions from comments however the above error is now seen.

Comment: The error saying that you can't create an integer from empty data. That means that at some point this line `valInt, err := strconv.Atoi(val)` the value in `val` is equal to "".  What integer would `""` be converted to?  Either make sure all the cells are correct, add an if statement above `if val != "" {do something}`, or don't `log.Fatal` instead make `valInt = 0` or `-1` to indicate an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means one of the cells of your CSV is blank, I reproduced the error with this code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    matrix1 := [5][5]int{}

    file := strings.NewReader("1,2,3,4,5\n6,7,8,,0")
    lines, _ := csv.NewReader(file).ReadAll()
    for i, line := range lines {
        for j, val := range line {
            valInt, err := strconv.Atoi(val)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            matrix1[i][j] = valInt
        }
    }
}
```

If you are ok with treating blank cells as 0 this will get you past the error:

```
func main() {
    matrix1 := [5][5]int{}

    file := strings.NewReader("1,2,3,4,5\n6,7,8,,0")
    lines, _ := csv.NewReader(file).ReadAll()
    for i, line := range lines {
        for j, val := range line {
            var valInt int
            var err error
            if val == "" {
                valInt = 0
            } else {
                valInt, err = strconv.Atoi(val)
            }
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            matrix1[i][j] = valInt
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've added a little more to my question regarding outputting the resulting matrix.

Comment: @benjano In the case of the CSV Writer method, it takes a `[]string` and currently you are attempting to pass a `string. Eliminate the inner loop, and replace it with `writer.Write(line2)`

Comment: Hi, I've done what I believe you have suggested but an error is still given. Any further tips?

Comment: `for _, line2` instead of `for line2` learn more about that here: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for

Comment: cannot use line2 (type [1500]int) as type []string in argument to writer.Write - The following error is given now, is it right that my range is blank, blank is a global matrix variable which my resulting answers are written too. I will go through the golang doc now to understand it better.

Comment: Looks like that is a slice of `int` so you need to convert that into a slice of `string` before you can pass it to the `Write` method. You can use `strconv.FormatInt` for that

Comment: FormatInt requires a int64 to be passed into it, my matrix is a 2D array of type int with a size of constant n. Is FormatInt what I require, looking at the documentation it doesn't seem correct?

Comment: You can cast from int to int64, assuming x is some int: `newx := int64(x)`

Answer (score 0):

As mentions in the comments above the error was due to a missing value in my csv file.

Once the file was amended the error is now gone.